# Angularjs $http mock issues

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, debugging, karma-runner

I need a little help formatting my unit test to get the expected results from testacular/karma

```
beforeEach( inject( function( customService, $httpBackend ){            
         service = customService;
         $http = $httpBackend
;}))

it('should make a default call upon initialization',function(){

var modalObj = {
                 "id": null,
                 "contentId": null,
                 "isActive":false,
                 "websiteId":2000,
                 "createdByUserName":"haselton",
                 "text":"another micro",
                 "tags":[],
                 "something random":null,
                 "something else":3
              },
              requestObj = {"isActive":false,"tags":[],"websiteId":2000,"createdByUserName":"haselton","text":"another micro"},
            mbObj = {};


         $http.whenPOST('/url/of/call', [requestObj]).respond(
             {
                 "id": 40,
                 "contentId": null,
                 "isActive": false,
                 "creationDate": "05/22/2013 14:24:14 PDT",
                 "lastModifiedDate": "05/22/2013 14:24:14 PDT",
                 "lastModifiedStatusDate": null,
                 "websiteId": 2000,
                 "createdByUserName": "haselton",
                 "text": "another micro",
                 "tags": []
             }
         );
```

Then I have a service that spawns the call and returns a promise.  Here is the rest of the test:

```
         mbObj = service.createEntry(modalObj); // returns a promise
         mbObj.then(function(data){
             console.log(data);
             expect( angular.isNumber(data.id)).toBe(true);
             expect(data.isActive).toBe(false);
             expect(data.tags).toBe( 0 );
             expect(data.websiteId).toBe(2000);
             expect(data.createdByUserName).toBe("haselton");
             expect(data.text).toBe("another micro");
         }); 

         $http.flush();

});
```

Instead of passing, the console.log inside of the fulfilled promise logs out Angular Resources.  Here is a screen shot:
[image]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks!

Comment: You should probably be using [$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend) to mock your `$http` calls.

Comment: @JonathanPalumbo sorry for not showing that in the example, but the $httpBackend is actually being used.  I updated the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` argument resolved for the `modalObj` request is an array, so use the subscript to get the actual data:

```
console.log(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3] , data[4], data[5], data[6], data[7], data[8], data[9]);
```